# How to get rid of horizontal scrollbar when placing map inside container?

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to display a google map component on my website and whenever I add the component, the map extends beyond the width of the website and results in a horizontal scrollbar as follow

[image: as such]

I have the following styling for the map and the container that holds the map component. I am not sure what am I doing wrong and would appreciate if anyone can help point out the mistake. How can I change my styling?

```
const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '50%',
  justifyContent: "center",
  align: "center",
  overflow: 'hidden'
 
};
 root: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(4),
    height: 550,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    overflow: 'hidden'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanna wrap this map element with a div and add the following styles to it:

```
div{
max-width: 800px;
width: 100%;
}
```

This will prevent the div to ever go beyond 800px - if the screen is smaller than 800px it will shrink down instead of extending that width.

You can change the "800px" to any value you'd like, usually you want it to be the size of your website's `wrapper` class.